# Auto Thresholding on R raster object

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Is there an auto-thresholding algorithm such as 'Otsu' available for R raster object. I have tried using the "authothresholder" package, however it is inefficient as it works on matrix and  doesn't work with 32 bit tif files. I am trying to convert an NDWI image into a binary layer.

Comment: The matlab code in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method took about five minutes to convert to R. Its meant for 256 bins (ie pixel counts in 8 bit images) but I suspect NDWI is something like a (0,1) interval so might need some adjustment - have you tried tdhat?

Comment: The `classInt` package implements the `jenks` method for finding classes and I think the Jenks intervals with two classes might be identical to the Otsu threshold...

Comment: What do you want to base your threshold on? You can do   `x <- r > 0.5`

Comment: I wanted to use one of the 'auto thresholding' methods. As others have suggested I could implement it using the available R packages such as classInt, authothresholder or EBImage.   However, this would be quite inefficient as they are not meant from spatial data. I will try using these packages to estimate the threshold(t) value and apply x <- r >t, as suggested. I was wondering if someone had a more efficient way of approaching this.

Comment: @Arihant if you include an example dataset in your question, maybe we could do some benchmarking? Otherwise, I don't see how the methods mentioned could be improved much, other than perhaps sampling before auto-thresholding.

Answer (score 3):

This is implemented in the `EBImage` package available from Bioconductor. Here is an example use:

```
library(EBImage)
img <- readImage(system.file("images", "sample.png", package = "EBImage"))
thr <- img > otsu(img)
display(img)
display(thr)
```

The implementation is essentially the following (pulled from the function definition of `EBImage::otsu` i.e. not my work), so you should be able to adapt the following for whatever image analysis toolset you are using:

```
img  # assuming img is a numeric matrix or vector

range = c(0, 1)  # assuming values in the matrix range from 0 to 1
levels = 256L
breaks = seq(range[1], range[2], length.out = levels + 1)

h = hist.default(img, breaks = breaks, plot = FALSE)
counts = as.double(h$counts)
mids = as.double(h$mids)
len = length(counts)
w1 = cumsum(counts)
w2 = w1[len] + counts - w1
cm = counts * mids
m1 = cumsum(cm)
m2 = m1[len] + cm - m1
var = w1 * w2 * (m2/w2 - m1/w1)^2
maxi = which(var == max(var, na.rm = TRUE))
(mids[maxi[1]] + mids[maxi[length(maxi)]])/2
```